# How can a Swift module/class work around the lack of language support for "protected" members?

Tags: swift, access-control

I'm faced with a situation where I am defining a reusable base class in a module, and I want to provide certain functions that should be callable only by subclasses, not external users of that subclass.

I'm writing a framework and packaging it as a Swift module. Part of my framework includes a base class that can be subclassed to add functionality, but whereby the derived class also has a further external purpose as well. Imagine defining a new kind of view: it derives from `UIView` or `NSView`, then provides additional logic, and is then itself instantiated by another party.

In this case, I'm the one defining the `UIView`-like class that is intended to be subclassed, and along with it comes a lot of private `UIView` internal stuff, like measurement, arranging, who knows, internal stuff.

The point is, end users of this new view class don't want to see the internals of the architecture that supported the subclassing, those should be completely inside the black box of what the subclass represents.

And it strikes me that this is now impossible in Swift.

I really don't understand why Swift got rid of `protected` access control. [According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11), the function that I want to expose only to subclasses "isn't really useful outside the subclass, so protection isn’t critical".

Am I missing something? Is this a whole class of design patterns that Swift simply cannot support?

One thought that occurs to me is I could perhaps split up the public-public and the private-public parts of my class into two parts, perhaps using protocols, whereby public-public users would only see the public protocol and "private" public users would see the "private" protocol as well. Alas this seems like a lot of engineering for something that used to be free.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11) set of reasons? Sounds like it's not an issue of what they can support. It sounds like they gave it some serious thought and decided that `protected` is problematic at best, and not very useful. (If you've already read that set of reasons, never mind.)

Comment: @GreatBigBore Yes that is what I was referring to. I updated the question with the link and further commentary.

Comment: So far I've been using `fileprivate` for a lot of my needs that I used to address with `protected`. But my Swift adventures haven't taken me into really deep water yet; maybe `fileprivate` wouldn't help with more serious apps.

Comment: Unfortunately `fileprivate` is useless on classes that are intended to be subclassed by third parties, such as in the case of a framework.

Comment: Swift team: "Let's introduce a new `open` class modifier that conflates access with inheritance, but get rid of `protected` because it conflates access with inheritance."

Comment: This could do with less discussion of Apple/Swift team and more explanation of what you need to do. Are you saying that you want to _override_ these methods inside the module? Do you want library clients to be able to subclass?

Comment: Added some further details @JoshCaswell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's isn't a Stack Overflow question; it's a suggestion for an improvement in the Swift language that's irrelevant to this site. It belongs on forums.swift.org.

Comment: @matt How is that the case? I'm looking for architectural workarounds for this limitation of the language, not looking to discuss the language. I even said as much in the question.

Comment: This is definitely a real, technical question that I think is welcome on SO. I'd love to see more like it. That said, I understand where matt's coming from, since I think you were still over-emphasizing the "complaint" part. I've moved stuff around to make the actual technical part more prominent.

Comment: If you object to my change, you're absolutely free to roll it back, but I hope you'll take the feedback into account in some form.

Comment: I’m more interested in discussing the issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, sorry.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sorry I was angry from the close vote. I appreciate the edit.

Comment: No worries, @devios1

Answer (score 3):

FWIW — I've been continually asking for better access control in Swift (including `protected`) since before there was access control in Swift. Now, 3.5 years after we were told to give the Swift approach to access control a try, Swift has been my primary language for almost 3 of those years and I still think the access control paradigm is clumsy and unable to model concepts that are easy in almost all similar languages.

The largest mitigating factor for me is that Swift has steered me away from ever using inheritance and subclassing 95% of the time, which I think is a good thing. So this issue comes up less than it may have otherwise. But for situations exactly as you are describing, there isn't an equivalent way to accomplish what you are doing using only protocols and protocol extensions, so you are stuck either polluting a public API with possibly harmful internal details, or using some workaround (like the one that follows) which has the smallest possible public API exposure, and simulates what you want at the cost of boilerplate and awkwardness.

That said, the approach I take is somewhat inspired by Objective C, where there is also no real `protected` access control, but the convention is to declare a public API header (which client code will import and reference) and a special "+Subclassing" header which only subclasses will import in their implementation, giving them visibility into the not-for-public-consumption internals.

In Swift, this isn't directly possible either, but given a class like this:

```
open class SomeClass {
    private var foo: String
    private var bar: Data
    public init(){
        foo = "foo"
        bar = Data()
    }
    private func doInternalThing() {
        print(foo)
    }
}
```

You can add a nested "Protected" wrapper via extension (has to be in the same file as your class declaration), which takes an instance of the class (or a subclass) and exposes the protected-level internals as a sort of proxy:

```
// Create a nested "Protected" type, which can accept an instance of SomeClass (or one of its subclasses) and expose the internal / protected members on it
public extension SomeClass {
    public class Protected {
        unowned private var someClass: SomeClass
        public var foo: String {
            get {
                return someClass.foo
            }
            set {
                someClass.foo = newValue
            }
        }
        public init(_ someClass: SomeClass) {
            self.someClass = someClass
        }
        public func doInternalThing() {
            someClass.doInternalThing()
        }
    }
}
```

Outside of the framework, in the client application, the protected members are accessed in a subclass like this:

```
class SomeSubclass: SomeClass {
    private lazy var protected: SomeClass.Protected = { SomeClass.Protected(self) }()
    func doSomething() {
        protected.foo = "newFoo"  // Accesses the protected property foo and sets a new value "newFoo"
        protected.doInternalThing() // Prints "newFoo" by calling the protected method doInternalThing which prints the foo property.
    }
}
```

There are pros and cons for this approach.  The cons are mainly the amount of boilerplate you need to write to map all your properties and functions from the Protected wrapper to the actual class instance as shown above. Also, there is no avoiding the fact that consumers will see SomeClass.Protected as a publicly visible type, but hopefully it's clear that it shouldn't be used and it's difficult enough to use it arbitrarily that it won't happen.

The pros are that there isn't a lot of boilerplate or pain for clients when creating subclasses, and its easy to declare a lazy "protected" var to get the desired API. It's pretty unlikely that non-subclass would stumble upon or use this API accidentally or unwittingly, and it's mostly hidden as desired. Instances of `SomeSubclass` will not show any extra protected API in code completion or to outside code at all.

I encourage anyone else who thinks access control — or really in this case, API visibility and organization — to be easier than it is in Swift today to let the Swift team know via the Swift forums, Twitter, or bugs.swift.org.

Comment: I've given this a lot of thought and decided that my best option for the time being is to simply name protected methods with a leading underscore, to emphasize that they are implementation details, and include a warning in the documentation. I've decided I don't want to invest heavily in architecting a workaround for such a fundamental limitation of the language, and if Apple continues to insist on removing fundamental parts of OOP, then I will simply make it clear that it is not by choice. Maybe if enough others adopt this, the shaming will convince Apple to change this.

Answer (score 2):

You can kinda, sorta work around it by separating out the for-subclasses stuff into a separate protocol, like this:

```
class Widget {
    protocol SubclassStuff {
        func foo()
        func bar()
        func baz()
    }

    func makeSubclassStuff() -> SubclassStuff {
        // provide some kind of defaults, or throw a fatalError if this is
        // an abstract superclass
    }

    private lazy var subclassStuff: SubclassStuff = {
        return self.makeSubclassStuff()
    }()
}
```

Then you can at least group the stuff that's not to be called in one place, to avoid it polluting the public interface any more than absolutely necessary and getting called by accident.

You can also reconsider whether you really need the subclass pattern here, and consider using a protocol instead. Unfortunately, since protocols can't nest types yet, this involves giving the subclass-specific protocol an Objective-C-style prefixed name:

```
protocol WidgetConcreteTypeStuff {
    ...
}

protocol Widget {
    var concreteTypeStuff: WidgetConcreteTypeStuff { get }
}
```